# Open a specific url with my app without removing other apps

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have an android app with manifest file like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:host="myurl.com"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

which means my app can open urls match whit a given filter.
In most android devices this works fine, but in some devices like samsung A5 2016 when user clicks on links like this android doesn't show other browsers and automatically open the link with my app.

I use normal Intent to open links in my app. But I can't fix the problem.

Can anyone help me?

It seems because I added intent-filter to my manifest file it blocks other apps to run this url.

I removed intent-filter from manifest file and it worked. But I wanna my app to be able to open urls which I mentioned in manifest file.

Comment: If you had accidentally pressed always open with this (you app) , then going forward the same will be used. Either clear the cache or delete the app and try again installing

Comment: No. I haven't set default app

Comment: If I remove <intent-filter> section from manifest it works and show all browser app

Comment: tried uninstalling and check. Not sure about the device. I have not used that

Comment: I'm pretty sure that does not solve the problem. because even in code when I ask for the Intent which can accepts url, only my app returns as result: getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(prototype, 0)

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: I removed intent-filter section from my manifest file and it was ok